# how to fix material tab host in android 5+

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I used (compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11') libariry to create Tab in my project . 
But I have a problem . 
[image]
As you see , there is a gap between Tabs and AppBarLayout in Android 5 and above.
but in androids with lower version everything is ok. 
what's the problem ?!?!?!

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_300sdp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:title=""
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
    android:id="@+id/materialTabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
    app:primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:colorPrimaryDark="#dedede"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:accentColor="#ffffff"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ir.persianit.doctors.DetailActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/detailsdoctors"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="ir.persianit.doctors.DetailActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/detailsdoctors">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Main.DetailsActivity"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
    >
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try TabLayout instead TabHost.
hope to help you